# Why does edit text and the spinner UI's corner get destorted?

Tags: android

I make an XML layout and when I run it on big screen emulator or mobile, its UI is looking good, but when I check it on a small screen the edit text corner gets distorted and the user interface is not looking good. Why?

Is this a density problem or some other? My XML is listed below. Check it on "qvga" target 4.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

        </ScrollView>
   </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the same problem. I solved it by changing the skin built in to HVGA... The procedure is as follows.

In Eclipse SDK, go to Window --> Android SDK and AVD Manager --> Virtual devices. Select your Android Virtual Device and click on Edit. Change the Skin Built-in to HVGA and Click on Edit AVD.

If you are already using HVGA, go for a higher version. I changed it from QVGA to HVGA. I hope this is an alternative to solve the problem on the emulator.

Comment: exactly but how to solve it for specific device means for emulator i change it but how for device if my device is small in screen?

Answer (score -1):

If you want that your UI should be adjusted according to the mobile device screen, you can assign a weightSum to the layout and layout_weight to widgets and it will display properly in all the screens.